# Error: "Invalid frame size (72): Could not seek to 72" while converting .mp3 files to .wav

Tags: python

I have a program that converts `mp3` audio files to `wav` audio files using `pydub` library.

Once I start to loop my directory with `mp3` files to create new `wav` files in the other folder, after 60 converted files I get this error:

```py
[mp3 @ 0x7fd3d1806c00] Invalid frame size (72): Could not seek to 72.
/Users/a123/Desktop/DeepNetsProjectAndProcessing/AudioFilesForTest/77750075959_in_2021_04_06-19_09_21_77472397479_xjeu.mp3: Invalid argument
```

Here is my Python code:

```
pydub.AudioSegment.ffmpeg = "/Users/a123/Downloads/ffmpeg"

mp3FilesDir = "/Users/a123/Desktop/DeepNetsProjectAndProcessing/AudioFilesForTest/"
wavFilesDir = "/Users/a123/Desktop/DeepNetsProjectAndProcessing/wavFiles/"

for mp3FileName in os.listdir(mp3FilesDir):

    wavFileName = mp3FileName[15:-4]
    input_file = mp3FilesDir + mp3FileName
    output_file = wavFileName + ".wav"

    # convert mp3 file to wav file
    sound = AudioSegment.from_mp3(input_file)
    sound.export(wavFilesDir + output_file, format="wav")
```